# Different response on similar requests Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to handle the response object from Gmail API with getting attachments from certain messages:

In my Gmail account i have 2 Labels:
Label_1
Label_2

both messages get daily reports from different web services and im using the Gmail API to first get a list of messages while im filtering a message with a Label and a query search string (q field) which contains a certain date (this is how i get only one message when i request a list)

with the response object Im able to get the message ID and then send another request with the message ID.

I want to download the attachments so in the response object im searching for the Payload.Parts field of the response object

In Label_1 response - Payload.Parts[0] contains the filename field and Payload.Parts[0].Body contains the attachmentID

In Label_2 response - Payload.Parts[1].Parts[0] contains the filename and same for .Body contains the attachmentID.

my question is: why this is happening?
why in one response i get the wanted fields in the first Payload.Parts and in the second i have to go deeper in the object's fields?

I've also noticed that in Label_1 response I receive an HTTP header which I dont get on the second one that I think may be related: DKIM-Signature

any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you get is just the RFC822-message parsed to JSON. The message might be `multipart/mixed`, `multipart/related`, `text/html` or something similar. It is best to write your code so you check all parts in the payload:

```js
var response = {
 "payload": {
  "parts": [
   {
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1142e23c551e8e05200b4be0"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 0
    },
    "parts": [
     {
      "partId": "0.0",
      "mimeType": "text/plain",
      "filename": "",
      "headers": [
       {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "size": 9,
       "data": "V293IG1hbg0K"
      }
     },
     {
      "partId": "0.1",
      "mimeType": "text/html",
      "filename": "",
      "headers": [
       {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "size": 30,
       "data": "PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-V293IG1hbjwvZGl2Pg0K"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "partId": "1",
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "filename": "feelthebern.jpg",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "image/jpeg; name=\"feelthebern.jpg\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Disposition",
      "value": "attachment; filename=\"feelthebern.jpg\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
      "value": "base64"
     },
     {
      "name": "X-Attachment-Id",
      "value": "f_ieq3ev0i0"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ_2xG3WOiLh6MbUdYy4vo2VhV2kOso5AyuJW3333rbmk8BIE1GJHIOXkNIVGiphP3fGe7iuIl_MGzXBGNGvNslwlz8hOkvJZg2DaasVZsdVFT_5JGvJOLefgaSL4hqKJgtzOZG9K1XSMrRQAtz2V0NX7puPdXDU4gvalSuMRGwBhr_oDSfx2xljHEbGG6I4VLeLZfrzGGKW7BF-GO_FUxzJR8SizRYqIhgZNA6PfRGyOhf1s7bAPNW3M9KqWRgaK07WTOYl7DzW4hpNBPA4jrl7tgsssExHpfviFL7yL52lxsmbsiLe81Z5UoM",
     "size": 100446
    }
   }
  ]
 }
};

// In e.g. a plain text message, the payload is the only part.
var parts = [response.payload];
var attachmentIds = [];

while (parts.length) {
  var part = parts.shift();
  if (part.parts) {
    parts = parts.concat(part.parts);
  }

  if(part.body && part.body.attachmentId) {
    attachmentIds.push(part.body.attachmentId);
  }
}

console.log(attachmentIds);
```

Comment: So there is no way to get a similar response? I have to never assume that the attachment id would be in one part or the other?

Comment: @LiorNaar That's right. It will differ depending on the message type, how many attachments there are, etc. It is safest just to iterate over all of them. There generally isn't that many parts, so it's no big deal.

Comment: The Gmail API message just mimics the MIME structure of the email, which is a tree that can be arbitrarily complicated based on nested MIME "multipart/*" containers.  For example, if someone attaches an email, that has an email attached, that has a PDF in it.